CSS спойлер, не работает по нажатию
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему не работает спойлер на CSS. Пытался сделать его на чистом HTML/CSS. Указал id input, связывал label с ним - не работает.


.details-section {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.hidden-checkbox:checked+.details+.details-section {
  display: block;
}

.details img {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}
<a href="#" class="btn">Abrir<img src="/arr.png" alt="Arrow"></a>
<input type="checkbox" id="details-toggle" class="hidden-checkbox">
<label class="details" for="details-toggle">
    <span>Detalhes</span>
    <img src="/down_arr.png" alt="Arrow">
</label>
</div>
<div class="details-section">
  <div class="details-content">контент



Главная проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку состояние не переходит из none в block и я не понимаю почему.

А какой смысл делать CSS-спойлер в 2024 году, если уже давно существует html-тег <details>, тем более если вы не пытаетесь его анимировать?

Ну и .details + .details-section очевидно работать не будет, потому что в показанном вами html-коде элемент details-section явно не соседствует с элементом details

А при помощи  я смогу сделать появляющийся блок снизу при нажатии на нужную мне кнопку? Пример - https://prnt.sc/5brED-EBoWlR

Если вы хотите оторвать заголовок спойлера от содержимого спойлера (звучит как кривой UX, но допустим), то переместите checkbox по соседству к details-section и используйте что-то вроде .hidden-checkbox:checked + .details-section, а вот уже элемент details пусть остаётся оторванным, он всё равно связан через атрибут for

...хотя если вы захотите менять стили элементу details при открытом спойлере, то так уже не прокатит... Ну тогда выносить checkbox высоко наверх в родительский контейнер и убирать + из селекторов что ли...

Если ты помещаешь  в  - все работает, но отображает некорректно (https://prnt.sc/Y_6f__LPEbxC)
Если ты не помещаешь  в   -  ничего не работает
Код: https://pastebin.com/XXnGgU2R

почему не работает? работает даже при явных ошибках в html разметке. Или вы что-то в своем куске кода пропустили. Но если у вас действительно чекбокс обернут в div и не на том же уровне, что и details-section - то логично почему не работает.
